# How to remove and add a Sprite type of data to the scene?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a Sprite type of variable:

```
var can: Sprite;
can= new Sprite();
addChild(can);
can.x = 5;
can.y = 5;
```

This Sprite is making a grid in my scene as shows below:[image]

How it makes the grid? 
I will pass it to a class named "Grid" to make the whole grid.

When I am going to go to another scene, I need to remove all child in current scene. So, I use the function:

```
  function clearAllTut(): void {
     //trace(numChildren);
     while (numChildren > 0) {
     removeChildAt(0);
  }
}
```

when I will come back to this scene again, all the other child are demonstrated except "can".

The problem is with the removing function? (then why all the other child will be demonstrated again except "can")

or I need to change the method of programming for a Sprite type of variable?

Comment: anytime you use addChild in the timeline, that object will not (or no longer) be controlled by the timeline.  You'll need explicitly remove it.    I'm not sure I totally understand your issue though.  Do you mean to say that the `can` object isn't getting removed when your `clearAllTut` method runs?

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis , No, It will be removed from the scene properly, but when I come back to this scene again, I can not see "can" anymore.

Comment: When is the code from the top of your answer (where you create and add `can`)?

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis , in the main timeline (did i get your question correctly?)

Comment: Is it on the frame that you get to when you  "come back to this scene again"?

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis yes, it is in the same frame